# Not able to read registry key for 64 bit Windows system with RegOpenKeyEx

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to read a value from `"SOFTWARE\\Company name\\Application\\Instance"` as a Administrator on Windows 64 bit for my application.

```
(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\\Company name\\Application\\Instance", 0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey) NE ERROR_SUCCESS)
```

I tried with `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` along with `KEY_QUERY_VALUE` in OR condition and I used __TEXT in front of the path `(SOFTWARE\\Company name\\Application\\Instance)` even though It is failing with error code 2("File not found") on Windows 64 bit system.

Can anyone tell me what could cause the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit you question first, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: What does the value of  GetLastError() ?

Comment: Is the same working on 32 bit Windows?

Comment: Yes it is working on 32 bit Windows system

Comment: Did you try KEY_WOW64_32KEY ?  Have you checked with regedit to see whether the key actually exists?

Comment: Yes I checked with KEY_WOW64_32KEY still not able to read the path for 64 bit system